# Integrating galib with a Windows form

Tags: c++, windows, forms, visual-studio-2008

I am using galib, a genetic algorithm C++ library from this site: http://lancet.mit.edu/ga/

I have successfully integrated galib with a console application using visual c++ 2008. I managed it by changing the runtime library in project properties from /MDd to /MTd.

However, when I tried to integrate with a Windows form application, it appears that clr canot compile with a /MTd flag, and I cannot figure out how to compile galib to use /MDd.

Have someone by any chance successfully done this integration?

Comment: Do you really need debug mode?

Comment: No, but I have the same problem without debug mode as well.